# Can i make design in pixel first then convert everything in em later?

Tags: css, xhtml

Can i make HTML Layout in pixel first then convert everything what ever needed in `em` later? is there ant tool or method to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert'?

Comment: Just stick to `px` for absolute sizing and `em` for relative sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "can" but it would be a painful and imperfect task.

Everything would shift *slightly*. It would take a long time to realign, resize, and reposition ***everything*** on your site.

Answer (score 0):

That would be quite difficult since `px` is an absolute unit while `em` is a relative unit.

Consider this markup for example:

```
<div style="font-size:20px;">
    <p style="font-size:10px;">The quick brown foxed jumped over
        the lazy dog<span style="font-size:30px">s</span></p>
</div>
```

The (approximate) `em` equivalent would be:

```
<div style="font-size:20px;">
    <p style="font-size:0.5em;">The quick brown foxed jumped over 
        the lazy dog<span style="font-size:3em;">s</span></p>
</div>
```

Which may not be immediately obvious.

Comment: @Joel Potter - yes but can't we convert later?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid. It's better to pick one and stick with it. The example I gave uses font-size, but it gets even hairier with dimensions (margin, padding, etc.).